# Update multiple field values at once using datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I am working on a project where I am using jquery datatable.

I have three columns in datatable

**Name** **Tpye** **Value**

**Value** is an editable field with a text box.

I have 200 data items and I want the user to enter the value for the items the user want and that should get save in the database.
I want the for to be submitted at once rather than saving each value individually.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you looked online and tried before posting the question?

Comment: Convert Dataable to XML and parse it.

Comment: @Manish Goswami I am using jquery datatable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server as database server, you can use table type for achieving this. Using table type you can pass your updated table as a parameter to your stored procedure and you can update value into your database table with the help of that table type.

You can query table type similar to the way you are querying the table in SQL.

You will easily get syntax for working with table types on searching the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something likebelow, COnvert your Dataable to XML likewise you can do Insert/Update.

```
DataTable YourTable = new DataTable();
            YourTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            YourTable.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            YourTable.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(string));
string XMLResult =string.Empty;

using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
 {
    YourTable.TableName = "XMLPRODUCTDETAILS";
    YourTable .WriteXml(sw);
    XMLResult = sw.ToString();
 }
```

> In SP

```
create table #UplaodXMLPRODCUT
    (
     Name varchar(200),
     Tpye varchar(50),
     Value varchar(15)
    )

INSERT INTO #UplaodXMLPRODCUT
SELECT 
PRODUCT.PD.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') as Name,
PRODUCT.PD.value('Tpye[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')as Type,
PRODUCT.PD.value('Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')as Value
FROM  @XMLString.nodes('/DocumentElement/XMLPRODUCTDETAILS')PRODUCT(PD)
```

Now Insert into Main Table

```
INSERT INTO ProductTable
Select * FROM UplaodXMLPRODCUT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table named `Table1` which has 3 columns like Id, Name, Add for example you can do it like this:

insert into Table1 (Id,Name,Add) values (1,'Ram','Delhi'),(2,'Ram1','Delhi1'),(3,'Ram2','Delhi2'),(4,'Ram3','Delhi3')

Now you will see that it will insert all four rows to your table at once.